# Bash extract text and file paths, filter, process and output

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I have an SVN server hosting repos with an apache frontend. Most repos use LDAP authentication, but some require external access using htpasswd for auth.

My apache conf for subversion repos uses a series of the following blocks in a .conf file (simplified)

```
<Location /svn/reponame>
DirectiveName directivevalue
AnotherDirectiveName "anotherDirectiveValue"

AuthUserFile /share/htpasswdfilename

<Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 123.123.123.123
    Satisfy Any
</Limit>
</Location>
```

In order to quickly find active external users, I can use something like the following

```
 cat subversion.conf | grep AuthUserFile | sed 's/.*\//\/share\//' | xargs cat
```

Which will cat the contents of active htpasswd files, like the following

```
username:password
username:password
username:password
```

To make this output more meaningful, I would really like to prepend each entry with the repo name from the `<Location xxx>` block, eg

```
/svn/reponame1 - username:password
/svn/reponame2 - username:password
/svn/reponame3 - username:password
```

Comment: Updated, I'm just after a one liner really.

Comment: Fair point. It being a single command or one liner isn't hugely important.

Comment: Can you please add a sample of the input file?

Comment: snippet of the file here http://pastebin.com/TJD4WbAF

Comment: Dont post snippets of files elsewhere. Just edit your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output.The main things you're missing form what would be a complete question are that the htpaswordfilename files aren't shown and your subversion.conf file references directories that just aren't necessary for us to have to create to store those htpasswordfilename files in to test against, and your subversion.conf only contains 1 block when presumably you want a script to work for multiple blocks. Simply create an example that we could test a script against.

Comment: Apologies, I was struggling to replicate the spacing and indentation of the actual file inside the stackoverflow editor. The pastebin link more accurately represents the real input. The 'htpaswordfilename' files contain sensitive data, which is why I have not posted them. They can contain absolutely anything, my goal is just to echo out the content of them. You are correct in your assumption that I need this to work with multiple blocks however. Sorry, I should have made that clear.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is what you need:

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS=" - " }
NR==FNR {
    if ( sub(/^<Location +/,"") ) {
        sub(/>$/,"")
        location = $0
    }
    else if ( sub(/^AuthUserFile +/,"") ) {
        loc[$0] = location
        ARGV[ARGC++] = $0
    }
    next
}
{ print loc[FILENAME], $0 }
' subversion.conf
```

The above is untested of course since you didn't provide testable sample input.